# Not displaying output in branching program Motorola 68K

Tags: assembly, 68000

I'm having trouble displaying any output to my answer buffer after going through the loop even when I put in 2 it doesn't show that as an output. I'm sure my problem is in the for, if, or factor blocks but I have been looking at my code for a while and nothing has helped. Any help is appreciated!

```
for:    
    cmp.l   D0,D3       *D3-D0 
    bne if      *!= 0
    move.l  D3,(A2)+    
    bra done    
if:
    move.l  D0,D7

    divu    D3,D7
    clr.w   D7       
    swap    D7
    move.w  D7,D6
    tst.w   D6
    beq factor

    addq    #1,D3
    bra for
factor: 
    move.b  #'*',(A2)+
    move.b  D3,(A2)+
    bra done            
    divu    D3,D0
    swap    D0
    clr.w   D0
    swap    D0
    subq    #1,D3
    bra for
```

Comment: `move.b  #' * ',(A2)+` does that work properly since string is 3 bytes?

Comment: and `move.l  D3,(A2)+` writes a 32 bit word into A2 buffer, which isn't displayable properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here:

```
move.l  D3,(A2)+    
bra done
```

writing the value itself and *as long* won't display anything, since it starts by zero, plus you have to add `#'0'`:

```
move.b  D3,(A2)
add.b   #'0',(A2)+  
bra done
```

same here:

```
factor: 
    move.b  #' * ',(A2)+
    move.b  D3,(A2)+
```

the first line is suspicious and probably assembler-dependent, since you're storing a 3-byte string in a byte...

the second line misses the 0 ascii code addition. I'd rewrite as:

```
factor:
     move.b  #' ',(A2)+
     move.b  #'*',(A2)+
     move.b  #' ',(A2)+
     move.b  D3,(A2)
     add.b  #'0',(A2)+
```